# List of possible values ​for the function parameter

Tags: javascript, html, jsdoc

[image]

[image]

I want to make a function that receives list of certain parameters as shown in the pictures above and show me list of possibilites, I tried to use JsDoc but could not find a solution. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance. :)

```js
function name(param: 'name1' | 'name2' | ...) {}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

Comment: Ok, but i want to do it in javascript if possible. :)

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_typings-and-automatic-type-acquisition

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HTML tag for it. For example even a `div` tag can be used

```
document.createElement("div")
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't get you.